# Power shell script for send all files from pc dir to ftp

Tags: powershell

i wanna write power shell script for send files to my ftp server files type .csv, but i'm getting error like this

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed."
At E:\test\test\transfer_data_script.ps1:12 char:1
+ $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)
```

My code looks like this

```
$Dir="E:\test\test\test"
#ftp server
$ftp = "ftp://ftp.test.com/usr/local/bin/php/test/domains/test.com/public_html/pizdu"
$user = "test"
$pass = "test-"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  
#list every sql server trace file
foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.csv")){ 
"Uploading $item..."
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)
```

Any idea why its not working? Any help ar advice will be appreciated

Comment: Does uploading with another client work?

Comment: with link /domains/test.com/public_html/pizdu in log writing uploading, but i dont see files in host. i found this code template in internet. Cant check with another client.

Comment: can you upload a  `.txt` file?

Comment: i cant, same error

Comment: Can you upload anything to that ftp site using any client?

Comment: i can, im using winscp for file transfer, but  i want write power shell script for it .

Comment: So uploading a `*.csv` using winscp works?

Comment: Instead of `$ftp+$item.name do `(Join-path $ftp $item.name)` - in it's current form it is probably ending up as `"ftp://ftp.test.com/usr/local/bin/php/test/domains/test.com/public_html/pizdusomefile.csv"` which is not valid.